# SSRS- default value for paramater works in design but not Sharepoint

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a date parameter that allows NULL.  I set the default to NULL and it works fine in the design environment (checkbox is checked).  When I push it to SharePoint and try to execute the report, the NULL checkbox is not checked. Any idea why?

I am using SP 2012 and SSRS 2012.

Comment: Does the report already exist on SharePoint, and you are making modifications to it?

Comment: Maybe delete the report  and republish it.

Comment: It exists. I just updated it.  If I delete it, the subscriptions will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when you change parameters, the report must be deleted and re-deployed.

There's a 7 year old Connect issue open with Microsoft that they haven't gotten around to fixing yet.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299372/report-parameter-defaults-not-updated-during-deployment